# Opengl performance Improvement glTexSubImage2D function

Tags: performance, opengl, opengl-compat

I need to improve performances for a part of my code. I refresh a global texture with a buffer of data. I use `glTexSubImage2D` to update the texture. And the final display is larger than original data, so I extend the display by `glTexCoord2f` functions.

Display is fine but the performance of the GPU is too bad for this part. Have you some ideas to improve its? I need to use the version OpenGL 1.1.

```
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, widthTexture, heightTexture, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, dataBuffer);

glPushMatrix();

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0); glVertex2f(-size, 0.0);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0); glVertex2f(size, 0.0);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0); glVertex2f(size, size);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0); glVertex2f(-size, size);
glEnd();

glPopMatrix();
```

Comment: You are very limited by OpenGL 1.1. I don't think there is much more that you can do to improve the performance of a texture upload unless you want to compress/shrink that texture. Are you sure that OpenGL 1.1 is hardware accelerated on your system? Some drivers can implement the fixed-function pipeline in software.